# Shortcut for Applying stored procedures in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, keyboard-shortcuts

Using MySQL Workbench, after editing a stored procedure in the built-in editor, the only way I know how to commit the changes are to take my hands off the keyboard, use the mouse, and click "Apply", which does nothing but show me a dialog box, on which I must click "Apply" yet again, which commits the changes buy yields YET ANOTHER dialog box saying that things went OK, on which I must click "Finish".

That's a lot of nonsense to mess with.  Is there a shortcut key that will allow me to commit a stored procedure with a single keystroke, or any other mechanism that will shorten the process?

Comment: what about using ctrl+shift+enter?, seem you have turn off auto-commit option within workbench, do turn that off as well.